# combine 2 objects in java

Tags: java, class, interface

I found this code at a search on Google:

```
public interface Combine {
    // Combines 2 objects
    public Object combine(Object o1, Object o2);
}
```

and I would like to combine two objects in the main class using the above code. How would I declare a Combine object to serve my purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would create a class that implements the `Combine` interface, and override `public Object combine(Object o1, Object o2)` to do whatever it means in your case to combine those two parameters.

```
class Droplet implements Combine { 

    @Override
    public Object combine(Object dropOne, Object dropTwo) {

        //write combine code for droplets and return a newly combined droplet

    }

}
```

Look at [Marcelos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8405046/104950) answer for a fancier solution using generics - this allows you to pass in the specific types you're interested in, and not just `Object`.

Answer (score 3):

Depending of the class, the logic of "combining" would change. First of all, the class needs to implement the `Combine` interface, and then you have to program the logic for the `combine()` method, for example:

```
public interface Combine<T> {
    // Combines 2 objects
    public T combine(T o1, T o2);
}

public class BagOfOranges implements Combine<BagOfOranges> {
    private int quantity;

    public BagOfOranges(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public BagOfOranges combine(BagOfOranges b1, BagOfOranges b2) {
        return new BagOfOranges(b1.quantity + b2.quantity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's just an interface. It does not describe an implementation. You need to create a class which `implements Combine`.

```
public Foo implements Combine {

    // snip...
    public Object combine(Object o1, Object o2) {
        // You need to implement this method.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Combineinator implements Combine
{
  public Object combine(
    final Object object1,
    final Object object2)
  {
    // implementation details left to the student.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyCombiner implements Combine {
  public Object combine (Object o1, Object o2) { 
    //logic to combine the objects goes here (i.e. the hard part)
  }
}
```

In other words, you need to actually write the code to combine the objects and then put it in a form like the above. If you need advice on combining two specific objects you should ask that in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Your given code is just an interface. You need to implement it to define your on 'Combined object'

A simple implementation could be like this.

Here the CombinedObjs just keep the reference of object need to be combined.

```
public class CombinedObjs implements Combine {

    private Object Object1 = null;
    private Object Object2 = null;

    public Object combine(Object o1, Object o2){
        this.Object1 = o1;
        this.Object2 = o2;
        return this;
    }

    // You can provide setters to get the individual objects

    public Object getObject1(){
        return this.Object1;
    }
   public Object getObject2(){
        return this.Object2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an instance of the Combine object since it is an interface. You should make a class of your own that extends the Combine interface.

Comment: What do you think of `new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){...}}`?